# Elastic Search - Query with dynamic object and wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in the following format:

```
{ "_id":1,
  "s_id":121211,
  "data_detail":{
      "name":"John",
      "phone_number":08089320xxx,
      "city":"ABC"
  }
}
```

I need to search data through elastic search which will query where s_id=? and any text which is available in data_detail object. Example s_id=121211 AND ABC. I need wildcard on data_detail object.

Keys for the data_detail object is not fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a bool query with multi_match and term query like this. I haven't tested this, but something on these lines should work I guess.

```
GET test_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data_detail",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "ABC",
                "fields": [
                  "data_detail.*"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "s_id": {
                  "value": "121211"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I provide wildcard on the query:"ABC"

Comment: Have you tried the above and also tried replacing the query "ABC" with your  wildcard, with the rest of the syntax the same? Ideally that should work the same way, but if you have tried it what result do you get?

Comment: Tried with the ABC and it is working. I need to put something like this *A*.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
           "query_string":{
              "fields":["data_detail.*"],
              "query": "*str*",
              "analyze_wildcard":true
            }
          },
        {
          "term": {
            "s_id": {
              "value": "121211"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```